# How to solve variable not defined error in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, undefined

```
Match (a)-[:RECEIVES]->(b) 
WITH avg(toFloat(b.rating)) AS avg 
WHERE avg > 2.5 
RETURN b.pID, avg
```

This code is giving me the below error.

```
Variable `b` not defined 
"RETURN b.pID, avg"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has (at least) 2 issues:

1. The `WITH` clause does not specify `b`, so `b` becomes unbound.
2. Since you are averaging across all `b` nodes, it actually makes more sense to return a *collection* of their `pID` values with the average value.

For example:

```
MATCH ()-[:RECEIVES]->(b) 
WITH AVG(TOFLOAT(b.rating)) AS avg, COLLECT(b.pID) as pIDs
WHERE avg > 2.5 
RETURN pIDs, avg
```

NOTE: This query will return nothing if the average is <= 2.5.